# Using Helm to install chart from Build machine to remote kubernetes cluster

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, kubernetes-helm

I am setting up jenkins pipeline for my project which based on k8s and using helm charts to install. I have a separate cluster which jenkins needs to install my app using helm.

My problem is how should I install using helm in different machine ? My jenkins server don't have helm. Is it good practice to use ssh commands to install in remote cluster ? Is there a mvn or helm client which can install charts in remote machines ?

Answer (score 2):

Helm depends on kubectl (which is used to access remotely Kubernetes API), both helm and kubectl are meant to work on "local" machine and connect to remote API. All you have to do is setup these tools (either in Jenkins globally or as part of the specific Jenkins pipeline) so that the Jenkins job can use them.

This of course depend on having network connectivity between the client and cluster.

You should not have to use ssh to deploy helm charts.